# Json4s custom Serializer doesn't work due to type mismatch

Tags: scala, json4s

I have a case class containing a field of password. For safety I need to mask it when converting to Json.
So I create a custom serializer for this, as below.

```
  import org.json4s.CustomSerializer
  import org.json4s._
  import scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime
  import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._

  case class UserInfo(
                       userid: Long,
                       username: Option[String],
                       password: Option[String]
                     ) {
    override def toString: String = {
      val ui = this.copy(password = password.map(_ =>  "******"))
      ScalaRunTime._toString(ui)
    }
  }

  case object UserInfoSerializer extends CustomSerializer[UserInfo](format => ({
    case jsonObj: JObject =>
      implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
      jsonObj.extract[UserInfo]
  }, {
    case ui: UserInfo =>
      implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
      Extraction.decompose(ui.copy(password = ui.password.map(_ => "******")))
  }))

  implicit val formats = DefaultFormats + UserInfoSerializer
```

But when I try to convert `val ui = UserInfo(123, Some("anonymous"), Some("xxx"))` to a Json string by `write(render(ui))`,  it always fails with

```
scala> render(ui)
<console>:22: error: type mismatch;
 found   : UserInfo
 required: org.json4s.JValue
    (which expands to)  org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue
       render(ui)
```

I have to use it as `render(Extraction.decompose(ui))`, or add an implicit conversion from `UserInfo` to `JValue` as `implicit def userInfo2JValue(ui: UserInfn) = Extraction.decompose(ui)`

What's the right way to make the custom serializer work as default ones?

Comment: BEWARE: Json4s is [vulnerable under DoS/DoW attacks](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+denial)!

Answer (score 0):

Method `render()` simply renders JSON AST, it does not know how to convert an instance of your class to JValue. Look at this [diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8ClE.png), which illustrates data transformations with Json4s. Long story short, if you want to render your class as a JSON string, you can first convert it to JValue and then render like you did:

```
 render(Extraction.decompose(ui))
```

or you can take a shortcut and use `Serialization.write` which does both operations internally:

```
 Serialization.write(ui)
```

In either case, it is going to use your custom serializer if it has been added the explicit formats.

Comment: I'm just curious why it works for scala predefined classes, like `val json = List(1, 2, 3); compact(render(json))`. I think I can make this happens for custom case classes by defining my own implicit conversion function. Not sure if this is how scala lib classes are working?

Comment: It happens because of a number of implicit conversions from common Scala types like String => JString, Boolean => JBool as well as containers List => JArray, Map => JObject etc. so in your example `List(1,2,3)` gets implicitly converted into `JArray(List(JInt(1), JInt(2), JInt(3)))` before `render()` is called.